# How to save a file in a folder within a S3 bucket using Flask?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I try to save images in a folder within my s3 bucket, but it always save within the root of the bucket, not the folder. Here is what my code looks like:

```
s3 = boto3.client(
"s3",
aws_access_key_id = Config.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
aws_secret_access_key = Config.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)

def upload_file_to_s3(file, acl="public-read"):
try:
    s3.upload_fileobj(
        file,
        Config.S3_BUCKET,
        file.filename,
        ExtraArgs={
            "ACL": acl,
            "ContentType": file.content_type
        }
    )

except Exception as e:
    print("Something happened: ", e)
    return e

return f"{ Config.S3_DOMAIN }profiles_name/{ file.filename }"
```

Profiles_name is the name of the folder. How to do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work for you:

```
s3.upload_fileobj(
        file,
        Config.S3_BUCKET,
        f"path/to/folder/within/bucket/{file.filename}",
        ExtraArgs={
            "ACL": acl,
            "ContentType": file.content_type
        }
    )
```

Comment: path to folder so meaning the name of the folder or the full path?

Comment: Not full, but starting from the bucket as a root,
like `f"profile/{file.filename}"`